# What combat tracker displays well on a television screen?

Tags: dnd-4e, tools

There have been numerous questions on similar topics but none of them really meet my requirements.

I am looking for a 4th edition digital combat tracker *that can be viewed easily on a 32" television*.

[Incombat](http://laughterforever.com/inCombat/) is a fantastic tool. It's exactly what I need. Except for the fact that the PC and Monster names are too small to read on a television at a distance of more than a few yards, even on the smallest resolution.

Excel/OpenOffice are definitely options, but those are my fallback. I'll use them if I have to, but I'd prefer something else that has the bells and whistles like incombat does (save reminders, condition tracking, etc).

**What combat tracker displays well on a television screen?**

Comment: Or maybe there's a way to "zoom in" or change the font size on incombat? Perhaps a setting I'm missing?

Comment: Dang, I was just about to suggest InCombat until I actually read the question! I would imagine that there is a zoom in feature, especially since it is browser based. At the very least you could try zooming your browser in.

Comment: @GPierce Unfortunately it's done in flash. Changing the zoom or font size in your browser doesn't affect it. I tried finding a flash setting for font size too, no luck.

Comment: That's too bad.. Having inCombat up on a TV sounds great for play. Surely there is some way.. Hmm, off to the googles

Comment: @dpatchery point of fact its done in Air, but thats really not relevant. But it is why you can download it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I emailed the [Incombat](http://laughterforever.com/inCombat/) developer and figured out a way to effectively use the program on a larger display with low resolution.

If you download the Adobe AIR version of the software, you can right click on the initiative list and click "Show Player View". This gives a new window with just the initiative list. It also has a "use large font" option. When maximized on a 800x600 resolution TV this looks great.

Answer (score 6):

I've been using masterplan on my laptop, hdmi to the TV in my friends living room.

The DM stuff says on my laptop screen.

The player stuff appears in the player view on the TV.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late on this (been a bit busy this weekend somehow).  I wanted to point to this program called [D&D4e Combat Manager](http://www.dragonpro.com/index.php?option=com_jdownloads&view=viewcategory&catid=2&Itemid=53).  I tested it once and found it useful more for a face-to-face game, but can be useful in some online games out there where an initiative tool is not there.  It will make the person's system act as a server when setup and when you put the information you want as well as the options the DM wants players to see, the DM on his screen can manage the HP and whatever and place effects as necessary.  This might be more for what you're looking for dp if the other program can't do any further.

As a side note, I tested this on my 22" 1080P monitor at 1920x1080 and it worked just fine since the window would have to be a Browser window that can read basic HTML and let refresh rates happen (may have to mute the browser's sound when using I.E.)

Answer (score 0):

[4E Turn Tracker](http://4eturntracker.com/) has a pop-out window for the players to view that scales very well (we run it on a 42" TV and everyone across the room can see it clearly). However, you'll want a laptop or something, because the DM version of the screen and the player version both run from the same computer but have different information (you can track hidden or unrevealed monsters on the DM side without the players know it's there, for example).